# What's the most efficient way to select a products sub products and sub sub products? Self-Referential has_and_belongs_to_many Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, self-reference

I am making a bill of material application.
A product can be a part of many assemblies and have many sub_products.
I have the following models:

```
models/product.rb
has_many :sub_structure, primary_key: "produktnr", class_name: "Structure", foreign_key: "produktnr"
has_many :sub_products, through: :sub_structure, source: :product
has_many :structures, primary_key: "produktnr", class_name: "Structure", foreign_key: "delproduktnr"
has_many :assemblies, through: :structures, source: :assemblie

models/structre.rb
belongs_to :assemblie, primary_key: "produktnr", class_name: "Product", foreign_key: "produktnr"
belongs_to :product, primary_key: "produktnr", class_name: "Product", foreign_key: "delproduktnr"
```

To select all sub products is easy:

```
@product.sub_products
```

But what is the most efficient way to select sub products and they're sub products?

Something like:

```
@product.sub_products.sub_products
```

Answer (score 0):

I know for sure there's a better and more proper way of doing that, but I ran into the same problem a few days ago, I know this is not pretty, I had to adapt to your situation, and I didn't test, but there you go:

```
class Product
  @@all_products = nil

  def self.all_products
    @@all_products
  end

  #You will have to call this right before getting the children products
  def self.cache_products
    if defined? @@all_products && @@all_products.nil?
      @@all_products = ActiveSupport::Cache::MemoryStore.new(expires_in: 5.minutes)
      list = Product.all.ordered.pluck(:id, :name, :parent_id)
      product_instances = []
      list.each {|n|
        p = Product.new
        p.id = n.first
        p.name = n.second
        p.parent_id = n.third
        product_instances << p
      }
      @@all_products.write('products', product_instances)
    end
    @@all_products.read('products').select{|c| c.parent_id == nil}
  end

  def self.get_children(products)
    children = []
    products.each do |p|
      children += Product.all_products.read('products').select { |j| p.id == j.parent_id }}
    end
    children
  end

  def self.products_with_no_children
    Product.where("id NOT IN (#{Product.all.pluck(:parent_id)})")
  end
end
```

Comment: I have tried to make a class method in Product, and it works. The problem is that this method trigger a SQL query for every sub product, which make it to slow.

Comment: Is it possible to make a single query to select all sub product that has no sub products their self?

Comment: updated the answer, again, it is not pretty, but it worked for me.